# Joomla move to another server/test env

Tags: joomla, upgrade, migration

I administer a website for a small local charity which has Civicrm 4.7.6 / Joomla 3.6.4 with php 5.6. I am wanting to upgrade all 3 to latest versions. In order to do this i need to create a test copy of my live site. When i do this using akeeba backup, civicrm is trying to access my production site. have seen civicrm documentation on this but it is undated and looks really old (references only Joomla 1.6 & 1.7). Is there a simple up to date step guide to get a working copy of my production site?

thanks 
Dave

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem with the domain change that I need to carry by using the following method. Would recommend to you too.

1. Go to Joomla > Add-ons > Manage.
2. Disable the CiviCRM add-in.
3. Install the [Akeeba](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) plug-in to make a backup. Create a backup.
4. Install the new server with [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-kickstart.html).
5. Update the current rows 76, 109, 181, 183, 219 in public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php and public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
6. Go to Joomla > Add-ons > Manage.
7. Enable the CiviCRM plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your settings file needs to be edited so that you're accessing the correct database. I'm assuming you already also did this for Joomla, otherwise it would be doing the same thing.

It looks like the page you need is this: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/filesystem/

This is what the page says:

**Joomla**

There are two instances of civicrm.settings.php in Joomla, within each of the components:

front-end at components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
back-end at administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
The files are nearly identical. The one difference is that the front-end file has the site's normal base URL, while the back-end file has /administrator/ on the end, pointing to the back-end of the site.

Comment: Thanks for this. If i understand what you say correctly, i should scan the 2 instances of civicrm.settlings.php and amend any references to my production location. If i update these two files then nothing else needs amending.

Comment: That should indeed be the case. I don't use joomla, but that is how it works on Drupal. And that seems to be the case from the link I gave.